# Read a hard coded csv file and iterate through each entry to detect empty values

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have written a script for iMacro that reads a CSV file to extract numerous login details in order for passwords to be updated. The majority of these login details then also need to be updated on a second website, but in order to do so I need to be able to determine which sites have login details for the second site, and if they do, then run the second part of the iMacro script.

The CSV file I am using is laid out like so;

```
USERNAME 1 HEADER,   PASSWORD 1 HEADER,   USERNAME 2 HEADER,   PASSWORD 2 HEADER
username1.1,         password1.1,         username1.2,         password1.2
username2.1,         password2.1,         username2.2,         password2.2
username3.1,         password3.1,         ,                    ,
username4.1,         password4.1,         username4.2,         password4.2
```

A loop would be used to process one row at a time, with a if statement inside to determine whether or not a empty/null value is present. If the second username or password are empty/null then the second part of the iMacro script would be skipped and the loop incremented.

I've never really used Javascript before, but I've have a bit of a look around and found [jQuery-CSV](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/), which looks like it's what I need but I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I also found [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), which goes into detail about how to input a file, but it doesn't say how to hardcode it to a local file.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go
HTML

```
<textarea id="csv"></textarea>
<button id="run">Run</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#run").click(function(){
    var result = $.csv.toArrays($("#csv").val());
    empty = "";
    html = "<table>";
    for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        html += "<tr>";
        for(j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++){
            html +="<td>"+result[i][j]+"</td>";

            if(result[i][j].trim() == ""){
                empty += "cell "+i+" "+j+" is empty";
                empty += "<br />";
            }
        }
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    $("#result").html(html);
    $("#result").append(empty);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4J8Jb/

EDIT:
and to read the csv from a file you can use $.get like so

```
$.get('/path/to/file.txt',function(data) {
   if (data == "ON") {
       var result = $.csv.toArrays(data);
       ....
       ....
       ....
   } else {
       //there is an error reading the file
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the speed reply!
I've been trying to get it to work for the last hour or so and it will just not display any thing. The original code where I put the data into a textbox does nothing even though I literally copied and pasted your code and added the the links to the .js files in the head section.

The only progress I've made is when using your later piece of code to make it read in automatically. The exact code I'm using is [here](http://www.pastebucket.com/19657), but the only thing that displays when I the page locally is "Fail". (The csv file is in the same dir as the html file)

Comment: I tested the first code, haven't tested the second part of code. Can you check your console for errors?

Comment: for those from google like me, this requires https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv